# Repeat a Promise until an array is a certain length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, bluebird

In an effort to improve the speed when constructing an Array to send to the client-side, the number of results are being paginated on the client-side and thus reduced on the server-side.

Calling an external API, we thought to limit the number of results returned by the API to find the *minimum* number of API results that will fulfill the *maximum* number of results to be shown on the client-side (not every result returned by the API is relevant).

To do that, we think we need to repeat our promise, **until the array reaches the desired length (i.e. 20 objects in the array)** - is there a right way to do this?

(And overall would this approach be considered a good method to optimize the performance for such results? Also not sure if the structure of the promise below is even the proper way to sequentially loop through and modify this data...)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

// iterate sequentially, and return a modified array
function mapSeries(things, fn) {
  var results = [];
  return Promise.each(things, function(value, index, length) {
    var ret = fn(value, index, length);
    results.push(ret);
    return ret;
  }).thenReturn(results).all();
}


AcquireCredentials(Tokens).then(Credentials => {

  var ArrayForClient = []; // ARRAY TO BE SENT TO THE CLIENT SIDE

  const ExternalAPI = APIprovider({auth: Credentials});

  // INSERT SOME SORT OF PROMISIFIED WHILE LOOP HERE?

  return ExternalAPI.top_level_call({
    "parameter": "value",
    "numberofresults": 10
  }).then(function(first_results) {

        // loop through each result of the first_results.data array
        return mapSeries(first_results.data, function(result_of_first_call){

          return ExternalAPI.detail_level_call({
            "parameter": result_of_first_call.value
          }).then(function(second_results) {

                // loop through each result of the second_results.data array
                return mapSeries(second_results.data, function(result_of_second_call) {

                    // loop through each element in the result_of_second_call.array
                    return mapSeries(result_of_second_call.array, function(result_of_second_call_array_element) {

                        if (result_of_second_call_array_element.parameter == 'ElementA') {

                          // construct a new array containing data from the result_of_second_call_array_element
                          const ConstructedArrayA = ConstructArrayFunction(result_of_second_call_array_element);

                          // loop through the new ConstructedArrayA
                          return mapSeries(ConstructedArrayA, function(ConstructedArrayA_Element) {

                            // DO STUFF WITH EACH ConstructedArrayA_Element TO POPULATE ArrayForClient

                          });

                        } else if (result_of_second_call_array_element.parameter == 'ElementB') {

                          // construct a new array containing data from the result_of_second_call_array_element
                          const ConstructedArrayB = ConstructArrayFunction(result_of_second_call_array_element);

                          // loop through the new ConstructedArrayB
                          return mapSeries(ConstructedArrayB, function(ConstructedArrayB_Element) {

                            // DO STUFF WITH EACH ConstructedArrayB_Element TO POPULATE ArrayForClient

                          });

                        }

                  });

              });

        });

      });

    }).then(function(result) {

      // loop through each object in the ArrayForClient
      return mapSeries(ArrayForClient, function(ArrayForClient_Object) {

        // DO STUFF WITH EACH ArrayForClient_Object TO POPULATE ADDITIONAL DATA IN ArrayForClient

      });

    }).then(function(result) {

      log.info("Promise Complete!"); // This will run after the last step is done

      // An example of what ArrayForClient looks like
      // ArrayForClient = [
      //    {
      //      parameterX : "valueX",
      //      parameterY : "valueY",
      //      parameterZ : "valueZ"
      //    },
      //    {
      //      parameterX : "valueX",
      //      parameterY : "valueY",
      //      parameterZ : "valueZ"
      //    }
      // ];

      // Respond with the JSON of ArrayForClient
      res.json({
        ArrayForClient : ArrayForClient
      });

    }).catch(function(err){

      log.error(err);
      res.send(err);
      throw err;

    });

});
```

Comment: Also, would `return Promise.each` be faster than `return mapSeries` since we don't need the modified array that mapSeries produces?

Comment: is there anyway you could modify your example so that I could run it? it would help me to answer your question